# How do you add a method to an existing class in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

The [Int class](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Int) has a method `is_prime`, so I figured, just for giggles, I'd like to add some other methods to `Int` for some of my hobby projects that do number theory stuff.

I thought I could do something like this:

```
class Int {
    method is-even (Int:D $number ) returns Bool:D {
        return False if $number % 2;
        return True;
        }
    }

say 137.is-even;
```

But that doesn't work:

```
===SORRY!===
P6opaque: must compose before allocating
```

I don't know if this means that I can't do that or that I'm doing it incorrectly.

I could easily make a new class that inherits from `Int`, but that's not what I'm interested in:

```
class MyInt is Int {
    method is-even () returns Bool:D {
        return False if self % 2;
        return True;
        }
    }

my $n = MyInt.new(138);
say $n.is-even;
```

I'm not looking for workarounds or alternate solutions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's syntactic sugar for this - `augment`:

```
use MONKEY-TYPING;

augment class Int {
    method is-even() returns Bool:D {
        return False if self % 2;
        return True;
    }
}
```

Augmenting a class is considered dangerous for two reasons: First, action at a distance, and second, because (as far as I'm aware), there's potential for <del>undefined behaviour</del> *deoptimization* as it might leave various method caches in an invalid state.

Thus, the requirement for providing the `MONKEY-TYPING` pragma before you're allowed to use it.

As an aside, note that `is-even` could be written more compactly as `self %% 2`.

Comment: @briandfoy: note that I changed the wording from *undefined behaviour* to *deoptimization* - by default, classes are supposed to be open; as far as I'm aware, class finalization is not implemented

Answer (score 6):

Huh, this works, which I thought I'd tried before and I like better than what I presented in the question.

```
Int.^add_method( 'is-even', method () returns Bool:D {
    return False if self % 2;
    return True;
    } );

say 137.is-even;
```

I'm not sure this should work, though. The [add_method docs](http://doc.perl6.org/routine/add_method) says we should only do this before the type is composed. If I call `Int.^methods` the `is-even` doesn't show up. Still, it seems to be callable and doing the right thing.

### Lexical methods

Playing more, I figured I could make a method that's not attached to any class and call that on an object:

```
my &is-even = method (Int:D :) returns Bool:D { self %% 2 };
```

This constructs a `Callable` (look at `&is-even.WHAT`). In the signature, I constrain it to be a definite Int value (`Int:D`) but don't give it a name. I add the colon after type constraint to note that the first argument is the invocant. Now I can apply that method to any object I like:

```
say 137.&is-even;
say 138.&is-even;
say "foo".&is-even;  # works, although inside is-even blow up
```

This is nice in a different dimension since it's lexical, but not nice in that an object of the wrong type might call it. The error shows up after it thinks it has the method to dispatch to.

Comment: it might or might not be a good idea to additionally call `.^compose` (or at least `.^publish_method_cache`) on `Int`

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: I don't think it is documented, and I'm not even 100% sure my advise is sound - it's just that `Perl6::Metamodel::MethodContainer.add_method` does `nqp::setmethcacheauth` with argument 0, whereas `Perl6::Metamodel::ClassHOW.compose` calls `Perl6::Metamodel::MROBasedMethodDispatch.publish_method_cache` which sets `nqp::setmethcacheauth` again

Comment: re the edit, what's your Rakudo version? my fairly recent one dies with `Type check failed in binding <anon>; expected Int but got Str` when invoking `&is-even` on `"foo"`

Comment: I get the same error. I'd rather get something like "no such method". My comment about `%%` came from something else happening in my test.

Comment: `.&is-even` isn't a method it's just syntactic sugar for `is-even $_`. Also the error message comes from the type of the Callable; since methods and subroutines are separate types, there is no good way to get the message you want.

Comment: ["If you create types through the meta-object system directly, you must call .^compose on them before they become fully functional."](https://docs.perl6.org/language/mop#Composition_time_and_static_reasoning).

Answer (score 4):

You can also simply call a sub like a method by including the `&` sygil:

```
sub is-even(Int $n) { $n %% 2 }
say 4.&is-even;  # True
```

It's just syntactic sugar, of course, but I've done it a few times when it looked more readable than simply calling the sub.

(I know you're “not looking for workarounds or alternate solutions”, but you posted some yourself, so I thought, why not?)

Comment: I noted this in my first answer. :)

Comment: But you used a funny method assignment, instead of simply declaring a sub.

Answer (score 3):

There's another interesting way to do this if you need it only for some instances of a class. You can decorate an object with a role:

```
 my $decorated = $object but role { ... }
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for: adding method to an instance. The class of the object must be able to `clone` I guess because I get: `No such method 'clone' for invocant of type 'Perl6::Grammar+{Nogil::NogilGrammar}'`

Comment: I got, It: what I was looking for was mixing