# Why is adding methods to a type different than adding a sub or an operator in perl6?

Tags: raku

Making subs/procedures available for reuse is one core function of modules, and I would argue that it is the fundamental way how a language can be composable and therefore efficient with programmer time:

if you create a type in your module, I can create my own module that adds a sub that operates on your type. I do not have to extend your module to do that.

```
# your module
class Foo {
    has $.id;
    has $.name;
}

# my module
sub foo-str(Foo:D $f) is export {
    return "[{$f.id}-{$f.name}]"
}

# someone else using yours and mine together for profit
my $f = Foo.new(:id(1234), :name("brclge"));
say foo-str($f);
```

As seen in [Overloading operators for a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55814075/overloading-operators-for-a-class) this composability of modules works equally well for operators, which to me makes sense since operators are just some kinda syntactic sugar for subs anyway (in my head at least). Note that the definition of such an operator does not cause any surprising change of behavior of existing code, you need to import it into your code explicitly to get access to it, just like the sub above.

Given this, I find it very odd that we do not have a similar mechanism for methods, see e.g. the discussion at [How do you add a method to an existing class in Perl 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504849/how-do-you-add-a-method-to-an-existing-class-in-perl-6), especially since perl6 is such a method-happy language. If I want to extend the usage of an existing type, I would want to do that in the same style as the original module was written in. If there is a .is-prime on Int, it must be possible for me to add a .is-semi-prime as well, right?

I read the discussion at the link above, but don't quite buy the "action at a distance" argument: how is that different from me exporting another multi sub from a module? for example the rust way of making this a lexical change (Trait + impl ... for) seems quite hygienic to me, and would be very much in line with the operator approach above.

More interesting (to me at least) than the technicalities is the question if language design: isn't the ability to provide new verbs (subs, operators, methods) for existing nouns (types) a core design goal for a language like perl6? If it is, why would it treat methods differently? And if it does treat them differently for a good reason, does that not mean we are using way to many non-composable methods as nouns where we should be using subs instead?

Comment: perhaps to muddle this further: how or why is a method any different from a postfix operator?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question.  If you want to add .is-semi-prime, you can: `augment class Int { method is-semi-prime {…}}`.  For a direct parallel to a postfix, you'd just be adding a multi method instead.

Comment: @guifa: of course you can do the augment, but it is not something you can import and thereby compose, it's hygienic or lexically scoped so that the extent of what it does can be reasoned about. I guess that's part of why it needs MONKEY-TYPING. That is all fine, but I find it very much at odds with the way subs and operators work...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From a language design perspective, it all comes down to a simple question: which language are we speaking? In Perl 6, this is a question about which we always try to be very clear.

The notion of ones *current language* in Perl 6 is defined entirely in terms of lexical scope. Sub declarations are lexically scoped. When we import symbols from a module, including extra `multi` candidates, those are lexically scoped. When we perform language tweaks - such as introducing new operators - those are lexically scoped. Verbs in our current language - that is, subroutine calls - are those with a lexical definition. (Operators are simply `sub` calls with more interesting parsing.) Since lexical scopes are closed at the end of compile time, the compiler has a complete view of the current language. That's why sub calls to non-existent `sub`s, or references to undeclared variables, are detected and reported at compile time, as well as some basic compile-time type checking; future Perl 6 versions are likely to extend the set of compile-time checks that can be expected. The current language is the static, early-bound, part of Perl 6.

By contrast, a method call is a verb to be interpreted in *the target object's language*. This is the dynamic, late-bound, part of Perl 6. While the most immediate result of that is the typical polymorphism found in various forms in implementations of OO, thanks to meta-programming even the manner in which a verb is interpreted is up for grabs. For example, a `monitor` will acquire a lock while it interprets the verb and release it afterwards. Other objects might have been [constructed based on things other than Perl 6 code](https://github.com/Altai-man/ASN-META), and so the interpretation of a verb doesn't mean invoking code written as a Perl 6 method. Or the code might be somewhere over the network. Who knows? Well, certainly not the caller, and that's the point, and the power, and the risk, of late binding.

The Perl 6 answer to "I want to extend the range of verbs I can use with this object in my current language" is very simple: use language features that relate to extending the current language! There's even a special syntax, `$obj.&foo`, that allows for a verb `foo` to be defined in the current language - by writing a `sub` - and then invoked much as if it's a method on the object. However, the small syntactic distinction makes it clear to the reader - and to the compiler - what is going on, and which language is getting to define that verb.

Through the use of `augment` it is *possible* to extend the language defined by some type of objects. However, it's rarely the best way to do things, given that it will have global effect, and also scatter the definition of the language of the object.

Much of what we do in programming is about building languages. By that I don't mean new syntax; most of our new languages - even in a language as open to mutation as Perl 6 - are just nouns and verbs defined using standard language features. However, in any non-trivial program, we can't keep every detail of every language in mind at once. When I go to the restaurant and order a schnitzel, I don't know how the order will be transported to the kitchen, what the kitchen looks like, whether the schnitzel is hammered out, breaded, and cooked on demand, or just served from a (hopefully not too stale) cache of prepared schnitzels. The kitchen and I have just enough shared meaning to make the right kind of thing happen, but I don't know how they'll precisely react to my request and they need not know what I'll do in the meantime. This kind of thinking is acknowledged by OO itself - at least when we fully embrace it - and at a larger scale by concepts such as bounded contexts, as found in Domain Driven Design.

In summary, Perl 6 tries to help us keep our languages straight: to know what is in our current language, and what we express with only limited understanding. That distinction is encoded by the `sub`/`method` distinction, which also turns out to be a sensible place to hang a static/dynamic distinction too.

Comment: So why does SO not have a postfix symbol (like the mod diamond) for language designers? :)  Thanks for the authoritative answer!

Comment: thanks, that is - as always - an excellent answer. I very much like the "my language" vs "your language" idea, I guess that is something we all need to understand more deeply when working more with Perl 6.